# Reflection of the graphics about 2 lines

Tags: geometry, functions, graphing-functions

$y=\sin(x)$ is reflected first in the line $x=y$ and then in the line $y=2$ , what's the equation of the graphics ?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: i used geogebra to solve this however the answer is not correct

Comment: Why don't you solve it algebraically...

Comment: i could not so please help me to do this

Comment: Have you learned what a reflection is?

Comment: yeah only today and it's quite strange so please explain it to me

Answer (score 0):

The first reflection results in $x=\sin y$.

The second one results in $x=\sin(4-y)$.

> In general the reflection in line $ax+by+c=0$ results in the map:
>   $$(x,y)\mapsto \left(\frac{x(b^{2}-a^{2})-2a(by+c)}{a^{2}+b^{2}},\frac{y(a^{2}-b^{2})-2b(ax+c)}{a^{2}+b^{2}}\right)$$
>    which means: 
>   $$\begin{align}
> a=1,b=-1, c=0:&\quad (x,y)\mapsto (y,x)\\
> a=0,b=1,c=-2:&\quad (x,y)\mapsto (x,4-y)
> \end{align}
> $$